# Selected values could not fetched from drop down list present inside Modal pop up using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue in modal pop up in Angular.js. I have one drop down list which is coming in a pop up window.When i am selecting any value from list it is not reflecting in controller side.I am explaining my code below.

test.html:

```
    <a>
        <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='View' ng-click="viewtestImages();">  
        </a>

    <modal title="All Images" visible="testModal">
    <form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
     <select class="form-control"  id="status" ng-model="e_status">
     <option value="">Select Status</option>
     <option value="1">Active</option>
     <option value="0">Inactive</option>
     </select>
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="sendTestCode();"   value="SEND"/>
    </form>
    </modal>
```

When user clicked on `view` button the modal pop up window is opening .Inside is there is a drop down list.When user is selecting any value and clicking on `SEND` button i need to display the selected value in console message.My controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.viewtestImages=function(){
        $scope.testModal = !$scope.testModal;
    }
    $scope.sendTestCode=function(){
        console.log('check',$scope.e_status);
    }
```

Here my problem is inside the console message i am getting values as `undefined` after selecting any value.this drop down list is working outside of the modal properly.Here i need after selecting any value when user clicked on send button the selected value will reflected in console.Please help me.

Comment: Could you post more of your html so we can see where your controllers are located?

Comment: @tanenbring : i am using `ui-router`.One single controller is for this given page.I can also tell inside log message i am getting only text `check` but can not get the selected value.